# PHP Files not executing after using ' rm -rf * .' on /www/ and untaring new package

Tags: php, command-line, ssh, tar

Would like to start by saying I have no previous experience with SSH commands. Our new server doesn't offer FTP or cPanel for security reasons.

I successfully installed magento on the server but had an issue which required me to drop the database, and delete the magento files. I used `rm -rf * .` on the /var/www/ directory to clear it out.

I then untared (? correct term ?) the magento.tar.gz file again using `'tar -zxvf magento.tar.gz'` in the directory I want it and the php files aren't executing. They just return a 500 internal sever error.

I uploaded a phpinfo(); file to test if php is still working and it executes fine and shows me  what it should.

I'm not sure why these files aren't executing but in terminal the phpinfo file I uploaded is showing as green in colour but all of the php files from the tar.gz are black? I'm not sure if this is telling me something.

Did I delete something I should have by using `rm -rf *.` in the /var/www/ folder or is the fact that the magento extracted files are displaying as black in terminal while a php file I uploaded manually is displaying as green telling me something? Did I not untar them correctly this time?

Comment: Is the 500 error being returned by magento or by the server? If it is the former, it could be incorrect database details, or some of the folders require write access but don't? I cannot help if it is the latter, but the commands you have used look right.

Comment: have you got this line in your httpd.conf? AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

Comment: `showing as green in colour but all of the php files from the tar.gz are black? I'm not sure if this is telling me something.` - could be a problem with permissions. Green means "Executable" - you COULD for testing purposes try: `chmod -R 775 .` on the /var/www/ folder. If it works, try to figure out the correct permissions.

Comment: If you are using CentOS, Fedora or EPEL check SELinux context

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King The server is returning the error

Comment: @GeneSys - Yes I've tried to CHMOD the files but it doesn't change anything. Still black and seemingly non executable.

Comment: For testing purposes ONLY you could try to set the permissions to `chmod -R 777 .` (everyone is allowed to do everything on the files) - be warned that this may cause security issues! (So do it for testing/development purposes only). As Rajesh has noted in his answer: Look for `/var/log/apache/error.log` and see if there are hints what isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black vs green filenames have to do with file permissions. A lot of httpd instances are setup to not serve files unless owned by root, with group access to "apache".

To find out exactly what the error is on the server, you should look at the Apache error logs (often found at /var/logs/apache/) to see exactly why the server gives you an error.